# Angular: [disabled]="isDisabled()" is a proper way?

Tags: angular, performance

I am wondering if the below code is fine in terms of performance.

in html

```
<button [disabled]="isDisabled()">btn</button>
```

in ts (component)

```
isDisabled(): boolean {
  //...some loop calculation
  console.log('run isDisabled');
  return result;
}
```

The `isDisabled` method is executed all the time even you just scroll down the web browoser.

In the [official Angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#simplicity)

> A property name or **method call** should be the norm.

I can see that calling method is allowed but I feel it's kind of wasting specially there is a loop logic.

Can I keep using calling a method in `[disabled]` attribute in html or is there better way ?

Thanks.

Comment: why not create a variable and make it true or false inside your logic

Comment: Method calls are useful for special conditions, like disabling based on some user inputs.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Sometimes the condition of disabling can be complicated. So it has to pass some process such as method.

Comment: @Justcode I agree that method call is useful but if it exist in the html and it has a bit complicated logic with loop, I am afraid that it might occurs a performance issues.

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend to use function calls inside your html, because the function is called very often, like you said. In your case you can simply use a pipe or a boolean flag, which you set inside your component/service.

The pipe solution can look like this:

**disabled.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({name: 'disabled'})
export class DisablePipe implements PipeTransform {
    // Maybe you need additional params
    transform(arr: any[]) {
        // Do you loop over the array
        return result;
    }   

}
```

And in you html:

```
<button [disabled]="yourArray | disabled">btn</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is okay but not good.

Consider you have 500 iterations in your for loop, on any change detection this might run. Usually the best way is to use Observable API do declare dependent values, since you can then use the async pipe.

Comment: I thought using Subject could be the solution. However if I use the Subject, then I have to call like my.subject.next(true/false) all the time whenever i need to evaluate. I mean that works well but I am wondering if there is better way with Rxjs. So can you show me a example code please ?